# code for "delete full directory" returns warning

Tags: php, directory

I have folder, his name is "1", in this folder is 2 folders: "big_images" and "small_images"

I want delete folder "1" and his content, this is code:

```
function removeFullDir ($dir) {
$content = glob($dir."/*");

foreach ($content as $file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        removeFullDir ($file);
    }
    else {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
    rmdir($dir);
}

removeFullDir("1");
```

in localhost (XAMPP server, php version 5.4.4) this code works good. in remote server this code also works, but returns warning:

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

in remote server, php version is 5.2.42

please tell me, why obtain I this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) does not return an array, which means that based on the documentation it must return `false`. This can happen when there is an error, but it can also happen when the directory happens to be empty:

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty
>   array if no file matched or FALSE on error.
>
> Note: On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.

To prevent the notice just guard against it:

```
function removeFullDir ($dir) {
    $content = glob($dir."/*");
    if(!$content) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason could be **open_basedir** restriction which means that glob() returns false and it will error at the foreach loop as **$content** is not an array, so you could check like:

```
//before foreach
if(is_array($content) && count($content) > 0) {
```